# disable service linux mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, services

I'm using linux mint 17 and I want to prevent a service from starting on boot.

I can stop the service with,

```
/etc/init.d/<service_name> stop
```

but it will start again on a reboot

On centos7 I would use the following command

```
systemctl disable <service_name>
```

How do I do this on mint 17 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **Linux Mint 17 based on Ubuntu** you have to use this because  it uses *upstart*  as it is the way on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/<service_name>.override
```

For **Linux Mint Debian Edition**, it uses System V init, so you can issue:

```
update-rc.d -f <service_name> remove
```

It will remove completely the *init scripts* for the service. So if you are disabling it for a while and you want it in the future, better use:

```
update-rc.d  <service_name> disable
```

This only change the scripts of the service from *signal start* to *signal kill*, preventing it to start.

In the future it will change to *systemd* for both of them.

Comment: is the path /etc/init/<service_name>.override or /etc/init.d/<service_name>.override

Comment: I can't test it right now but I'm very sure it is `/etc/init/<service_name>.override`

Answer (score 0):

service service_name stop    #just stop the service

service service_name disable    #it should disable on runtime

The disable mode can cause some trouble